# Cannot browserify exports default statement

Tags: node.js, browserify, babeljs

**Edit** This was marked as a duplicate of a question that has no useable answers. Here's how I addressed it:

```
var BASE = 'http://localhost:3001/'
export let {BASE_URL, LOGIN_URL, LOGIN_USER, LOGOUT_USER} = {
  BASE_URL: BASE,
  LOGIN_URL: BASE + 'sessions/create',
  SIGNUP_URL: BASE + 'users',
  LOGIN_USER: 'LOGIN_USER',
  LOGOUT_USER: 'LOGOUT_USER'
}
```

**Original question**
I am exploring some React code from [here](https://github.com/auth0/react-flux-jwt-authentication-sample). It has an npm script to browserify it which is:

```
"browserify --extension=.jsx --extension=.js src/app.jsx | uglifyjs > build/build.js"
```

However I cannot run this as it just freaks out on the ES6 code. I am not sure what setup the authors had. So I changed mine to:

```
"browserify --extension=.jsx --extension=.js src/app.jsx \
 -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] | uglifyjs > build/build.js"
```

This now builds "fine" except that code that is exported using `exports default` is undefined as in a file that contains:

```
var BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3001/'
export default {
  BASE_URL: BASE_URL,
  LOGIN_URL: BASE_URL + 'sessions/create',
  SIGNUP_URL: BASE_URL + 'users',
  LOGIN_USER: 'LOGIN_USER',
  LOGOUT_USER: 'LOGOUT_USER'
}
```

In the file that imports it:

```
import { LOGIN_URL, SIGNUP_URL } from '../constants/LoginConstants'
```

The `LOGIN_URL` and `SIGNUP_URL` are undefined.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I think export default take function and expression only. for object you need to make `export {  }`

Comment: `export { BASE_URL: BASE_URL, LOGIN_URL: BASE_URL + 'sessions/create' }`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra yes I suspect that this code was written while still in draft mode. I am not sure where to find a clear spec though. Links like this https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html list `export default 42;` as valid so a bit unclear.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export